# Making SQL query results 'PRINT'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query which I eventually got to work fine but what I really need is the results to be displayed using the SQL `PRINT` command. The reason for this is I am automating the results to be emailed, and if I can have them come out as printed text then I can just embed the results in the email using the tool we use here. Otherwise, the current results have to be attached as a file and I would prefer the printed text if possible.

I have tried to modify the query by adding `DECLARE` and `PRINT` but I am really confused and can't figure it out. The query has 2 CTE's in it pulling data from multiple databases. What it is doing is selecting all the sale numbers/ID's from our SAP system for yesterday and comparing them with our the Sale numbers/ID's from our POS system for yesterday to make sure every sale in our POS system is now in SAP. The query itself works fine.

How can I print the results of this query?

```
WITH CTE1 (SAP_SALE)
AS
(          
  select distinct convert(BIGINT,convert(varchar(15),WERKS)+(select RIGHT(convert(Varchar(20),BONNR),7)))
  as Branch_tx_no from [PDP].[pdp].[S120] WITH (NOLOCK)
  where SPTAG >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() -1, 101) AS DATETIME) AND
  SPTAG < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME)
),
CTE2 (AR_SALE)
AS
(
  select convert(varchar(15),branch_no)+convert(varchar(15),sale_tx_no)
  from [ARDB01].[PP_BODATA].[DBO].[sales_tx_hdr] WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE sale_date >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() -1, 101) AS DATETIME) AND
  sale_date < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME)
  and sale_type in ('C','L')
)
SELECT AR_SALE FROM CTE2 AS CTE2
  Left OUTER JOIN CTE1 AS CTE1
  ON CTE1.SAP_SALE = CTE2.AR_SALE
WHERE CTE1.SAP_SALE IS NULL
ORDER BY CTE2.AR_SALE
```

Comment: Assuming this is SQL Server, check out sp_send_dbmail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: If you're on SQL Server @Laurence gave a great answer... use the email  body text to output whatever you want.  You can use HTML if you change the body_format parameter or you can just attach some query results.  I think you have to set up a sending profile in the db, though, but it's not hard.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick replies. Yes sorry this is on SQL 2005. We use a script automation tool called Opalis to run most of our scheduled processes. I would run this query each morning and have the results sent to our helpdesk as part of their morning checks.  Thanks for that suggestion Laurence I will investigate that but ideally as all our scripts etc are currently in Opalis i would like to put this there with them but i will try your solution. Thank you.

Comment: What DataType is AR_SALE?

Comment: AR_SALE is 2 differant INT fields concatenated together, I am converting them to VARCHAR.

Comment: I don't know what Opalis is exactly but you can loop through the resulting dataset, either with a cursor or.... give the data set numbered rows, then use a while loop with a (set @var = select ar_sale from tbl where row=@i set @i=@+1 and print out each row, and use the printed info however you need to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a cursor and `PRINT` one row at a time. Or you could use XML-concatenation, if you do not have any special characters in the result:

```
DECLARE @txt NVARCHAR(MAX);


WITH CTE1 (SAP_SALE)
AS
(          
  select distinct convert(BIGINT,convert(varchar(15),WERKS)+(select RIGHT(convert(Varchar(20),BONNR),7)))
  as Branch_tx_no from [PDP].[pdp].[S120] WITH (NOLOCK)
  where SPTAG >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() -1, 101) AS DATETIME) AND
  SPTAG < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME)
),
CTE2 (AR_SALE)
AS
(
  select convert(varchar(15),branch_no)+convert(varchar(15),sale_tx_no)
  from [ARDB01].[PP_BODATA].[DBO].[sales_tx_hdr] WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE sale_date >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() -1, 101) AS DATETIME) AND
  sale_date < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME)
  and sale_type in ('C','L')
)
SELECT @txt = (
SELECT CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+AR_SALE FROM CTE2 AS CTE2
  Left OUTER JOIN CTE1 AS CTE1
  ON CTE1.SAP_SALE = CTE2.AR_SALE
WHERE CTE1.SAP_SALE IS NULL
ORDER BY CTE2.AR_SALE
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)');

PRINT @txt;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use PRINT you can combine results of your query into a comma (or other char) separated VARCHAR variable and then print that variable, e.g.

```
DECLARE @sTMP varchar(1000)
SET @sTMP = ''

-- Your CTE....
SELECT @sTMP = @sTMP + AR_SALE + ',' FROM CTE2 AS CTE2
  Left OUTER JOIN CTE1 AS CTE1
  ON CTE1.SAP_SALE = CTE2.AR_SALE
WHERE CTE1.SAP_SALE IS NULL
ORDER BY CTE2.AR_SALE

PRINT @sTMP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE1 (SAP_SALE)
AS
(          
  select distinct convert(BIGINT,convert(varchar(15),WERKS)+(select RIGHT(convert(Varchar(20),BONNR),7)))
  as Branch_tx_no from [PDP].[pdp].[S120] WITH (NOLOCK)
  where SPTAG >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() -1, 101) AS DATETIME) AND
  SPTAG < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME)
),
CTE2 (AR_SALE)
AS
(
  select convert(varchar(15),branch_no)+convert(varchar(15),sale_tx_no)
  from [ARDB01].[PP_BODATA].[DBO].[sales_tx_hdr] WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE sale_date >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() -1, 101) AS DATETIME) AND
  sale_date < CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS DATETIME)
  and sale_type in ('C','L')
)
SELECT AR_SALE, row_number() over (order by AR_SALE) as r
into #temp  -- added this row right here 
FROM CTE2 AS CTE2
  Left OUTER JOIN CTE1 AS CTE1
  ON CTE1.SAP_SALE = CTE2.AR_SALE
WHERE CTE1.SAP_SALE IS NULL
ORDER BY CTE2.AR_SALE
```

then...

```
declare @x varchar(100) 
declare @i int 
    set @i = 1 

while (@i <= (select max(r) from #temp)) begin
    select @x=AR_SALE from #temp where r=@i
    print @x
    set @i=@i+1
end
```